# How to show field from linked model in crud for Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I have two model Users and Roles connected by a pivot table. I want to display a field from the role model in CrudUserController. For example
User model:

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany( Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Role model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( User::class, 'role_user','role_id','user_id');
}
```

UserCrudController

```
$this->crud->addFields([
    [
        'type' => 'repeatable',
        'label' => 'Role',
        'name' => 'roles', <- this field shows select2 with a list of roles
        'subfields' => [
           [
               'name'  => 'description', <- this field is from the role model, it should change when changing the role in select2 
               'label' => 'Description',
               'type'  => 'text',
           ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

I'm not sure if this is possible because usually such manipulations are implemented using js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create inline entries I would suggest to use the `InlineCreateOperation`, it can work in a `BelongsToMany` field too: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-inline-create

Cheers